# What will this PowerShell code output to?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Will this code produce only the last line of the System eventlog file associated with event ID number 4201? I just don't get it. Help please!

Code:

```
     get-eventlog system | where-object {$_.eventID -eq 4201}
```

Answer (score 5):

Lets break it apart

- `get-eventlog` - Calls the `Get-EventLog` commandlet
- `system` - Passes as the first parameter the word "system" this causes the System Event log to be choosen
- `|` - Pipe the output of the previous commandlet as the input to the next commandlet
- `where-object` - Filters the input commandlet based on a filter expression
- `{` - The start of the expression
- `$_` - A variable that represents the current row being evaluated in the result set
- `.eventID` - Selects the EventID property from the variable.
- `-eq` - test that the left hand side is equal to the right hand side
- `4201` - the number 4201 to signify the event id we want to test.
- `}` - the end of the expression that is used to filter

As you see there is no part that only selects the most recent record. Thankfully because Get-EventLog returns the objects in order of newest to oldest we only need to add a `Select-Object` to the query.

```
get-eventlog system | where-object {$_.eventID -eq 4201} | Select-Object -First 1
```

- `Select-Object` - Filter out the result set based on some parameters
- `-First` - Select only the first X items where X is defined by the next property
- `1` - The number 1 to signify we only want the first result.

---

If our list was not in order we would need to add a `Sort-Object` to it too

```
get-eventlog system | where-object {$_.eventID -eq 4201} | Sort-Object -Descending TimeGenerated | Select-Object -First 1
```

- `Sort-Object` - Sort the result based on some parameters
- `-Descending` - Sort from largest to smallest
- `TimeGenerated` - Use the `TimeGenerated` property to sort

Note: you could drop the `-Descending` and change `-First 1` to `-Last 1` to also get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

It will output all of the event log entries that have that EventID.